# Fundamental theorem of algebra proof with complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

The part of the proof I am asked to show from my book states:

Let $P(z)$ be a non constant polynomial in $z$. Assume that $P(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Show that $P(z) = P(0) +zQ(z)$ Where $Q(z)$ is also a polynomial.

Here is my attempt, I would just like to know if this is the right approach or if I have no clue what I'm doing:

As $P(z)$ is a non constant polynomial it has the form of $P(z)=a_nz^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} .... a_1z +a_0$. It can be seen that $P(0)=a_0$ which is constant, so we can let $Q(z)= a_nz^{n-1} + a_{n-1}z^{n-2} .... + a_1$ and when we multiply this by $z$ we obtain $zQ(z)= a_nz^{n} + a_{n-1}z^{n} .... a_1z$.

Thus we can rewrite $P(z) = P(0) +zQ(z)$ as required.

I understand that this process might not be correct, but maybe someone can nudge me in the right direction to approach.

Comment: The statement you are asked to prove does not make sense: what is $Q(z)$?  Are you supposed to prove there *exists* a polynomial $Q(z)$ such that $P(z)=P(0)+zQ(z)$?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. It's true more generally that there exists a polynomial $Q(z)$ such that $P(z) = P(a) + (z - a) Q(z)$, which follows e.g. from the division algorithm or from just expanding everything in powers of $z - a$.

Comment: I edited it, we are given that $Q(z)$ is also a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Here is a more algebraic proof.

Consider $P \in \mathbb{K}[X]$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field. Then $P(X) - P(0)$ has $0$ as a root. Thus, $X$ divides $P-P(0)$, that is, there exists $Q \in \mathbb{K}[X]$ such that $P(X) -P(0) = XQ(X)$. Hence $P(X) = P(0) + XQ(X)$.